# typescript for of compilation

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I would like to compile Typescript as ES5 but *with* ES6 `for..of` syntax.

My sample code looks like this:

```
// test.ts
class Foo {
    bar () {
        for (var x of [1,2,3]) {
            console.log(x);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried compiling with es2015 generator and iterable libraries as follows:

```
tsc --target es5 --lib es2015.generator,es2015.iterable test.ts
```

Here is my  **desired output**:

```
var Foo = (function () {
    function Foo() {
    }
    Foo.prototype.bar = function () {
        var y = [1, 2, 3];
        for (var x of y) {
            console.log(x);
        }
    };
    return Foo;
}());
```

Here is the **actual output**:

```
var Foo = (function () {
    function Foo() {
    }
    Foo.prototype.bar = function () {
        var y = [1, 2, 3];
        for (var _i = 0, y_1 = y; _i < y_1.length; _i++) {
            var x = y_1[_i];
            console.log(x);
        }
    };
    return Foo;
}());
```

Is there a way to force the TypeScript compile to target ES5 with some special ES6 features (`for..of` in this case) turned on?

Comment: tsc doesn't give you that fine grained control over transpilation from what I know.. it's all in.

Comment: You need to run with target `es6` if you would like to preserve such code unchanged.

Comment: @just-boris: it must be es5 with just the for..of es6 feature. I was wondering if the additional libraries could make it possible.

Comment: Typescript doesn't support your kind of setup. So, there will be no solution

Comment: @just-boris I believe you are right.